# How to use Database First Entity Framework + Catel

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first, catel

I have some questions regarding the use of Database First Model and Catel. I have read the documentation and it seems like its based on a Code First design for models. I have also the limitation that other people are working on the same model and not using Catel as framework. So how could i use those models as base for my catel view models?  Is there an example on how to do it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to use Catel models as base models when using the EF stuff inside Catel.

If you don't want a reference to Catel for other assemblies, I would create a contract assembly (with interfaces for all services, etc) and only use Catel inside the actual implementation assembly.